# How to filter the styles based on the currData ID in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
currData = {
      "id": "iStyle1",
      "status": "PENDING"
    };

  data = [{
    "id": "splitStyle1",
    "styles": [
      {
        "id": "iStyle1",
        "code": "s1",
        "name": "Style 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "iStyle2",
        "code": "s1",
        "name": "Style 2"
      }
    ],
  },{
    "id": "splitStyle2",
    "styles": [
      {
        "id": "iStyle1",
        "code": "sl1",
        "name": "Style Layout 1"
      }]
  },{
    "id": "splitStyle3",
    "styles": []
  },{
    "id": "splitStyle4",
    "styles": []
  }];
```

How to filter the styles based on the currData id?

What I have tried is to used the filter. just like this.

```
 this.data.filter((x: any) => [this.currData.id].includes(x.styles.id))
```

but it returns empty array.

it should display the data which it has a styles.id equal to the currData.id

which it should be like this.

```
[
      {
        "id": "iStyle1",
        "code": "s1",
        "name": "Style 1"
      }, {
        "id": "iStyle1",
        "code": "s2",
        "name": "Style 2"
      }
    ], 
[
      {
        "id": "iStyle1",
        "code": "sl1",
        "name": "Style Layout 1"
      }]
```

Comment: Your styles is an array which may have multiple objects with id = currData.id. What would you want if more than one object inside styles array pass the condition?

Comment: @Ravi I updated to make it more clear. when the object inside the styles it should be filtered/display also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to filter like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vast3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

OK, So you want the entire items that contain a matching style:

```js
currData = {
  "id": "iStyle1",
  "status": "PENDING"
};

data = [{
  "id": "splitStyle1",
  "styles": [{
    "id": "iStyle1",
    "code": "s1",
    "name": "Style 1"
  }, {
    "id": "iStyle2",
    "code": "s1",
    "name": "Style 2"
  }],
}, {
  "id": "splitStyle2",
  "styles": [{
    "id": "iStyle1",
    "code": "sl1",
    "name": "Style Layout 1"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "splitStyle3",
  "styles": []
}, {
  "id": "splitStyle4",
  "styles": []
}];

const result = data.filter(item => item.styles.some(style => style.id === currData.id))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @BeginnerCoder updated the answer: `data.filter(item => item.styles.some(style => style.id === currData.id))`

Comment: it didn't remove the other styles from the array. when it's not equal to the current from the data it should display. instead it will remove. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vast3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: it should remove the "iStyle2"

Comment: @BeginnerCoder I'm no longer any confident to understand what you even want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768044/how-to-filter-the-rows-based-on-the-id-of-current-data-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  let result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {      
    let filtered = cur.styles.filter(item => item.id === currData.id);
    if(filtered.length > 0){
        return [...acc, filtered];          
    }
    return acc;
    
  }, [])

  console.log(result)
```

Comment: how to remove the empty arr?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder Check now. I have edited the answer.