# How to filter the rows based on the id of current data in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
     currData = {
    id: "iStyle1",
    status: "PENDING"
  };

  data = [
    {
      id: "splitStyle1",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle2",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        },
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle2",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle3",
      rows: []
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle4",
      rows: []
    }
  ];
```

I tried this data:

```
const result = this.data.flatMap(item => item.rows.filter((assetType: any) => assetType.id === this.currData.id));
```

but it returns empty array
and

```
const result = this.data.filter((x: any) => x.rows.some((rows: any) => x.rows.filter((y: any) => y)));
    console.log(result)
```

it doesn't remove the iStyle2 and I want to remove the iStyle2 from the rows. it should only display the data which it has iStyle2 in rows.

instead the output should be like this:

```
[
    {
      id: "splitStyle1",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    },{
      id: "splitStyle2",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

here's the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owuavn?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```js
const data = [
    {
      id: "splitStyle1",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle2",
      rows: [
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle1",
            name: "Style"
          }
        },
        {
          id: "1cUMlNRSapc5T",
          row: 2,
          sequence: 2,
          status: "ACTIVE",
          assetType: {
            id: "iStyle2",
            name: "Style"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle3",
      rows: []
    },
    {
      id: "splitStyle4",
      rows: []
    }
  ];

const newData = [];

data.forEach(element => {
    const filteredRows = element.rows.filter(row => row.assetType.id !== 'iStyle2');

    newData.push({
        id: element.id,
        rows: filteredRows
    })
})

console.log(newData);
```